# Algorithm for processing files multi-threading in specific order

Tags: linux, multithreading, algorithm, process, scripting

I am trying to implement a script (Python, Perl, etc) with multi-threading in Linux environment that will process incoming files in a folder based on their creation date in ascending order.

The folder will contain files that look like this :

```
user_a_20200530144720
user_b_20200530174720
user_b_20200530194720
user_a_20200530254725
user_c_20200530274799
user_a_20200530284720
user_b_20200530291234
user_c_20200531210101
...
```

At any given time, the server (Linux) should only be allowed to process 1 file of each user, and the file have to be the earliest for each user.

For the example above, only `user_a_20200530144720`, `user_b_20200530174720` and `user_c_20200530274799` files can be processed at the same time.

My attempted simple algorithm for this script :

1. Retrieve all the files in the folder in ascending order and store the files name into an array
2. Do a for-loop for the files array in ascending order
3. At each iteration, check if there is any a thread processing this user files by doing a `ps -ef | grep user_X | grep -v grep` (alternative is to check if the user lock file exists)
4. If there isn't any thread processing, move this file to another folder and spawn a thread (thats calls another script to process this file) to process it
5. If there is thread processing, skip this iteration to go to the next file
6. As the script have reached the end of the files array, repeat Step 1-6 again

However, for this algorithm, there are plenty of opportunities where the processing order will be wrong.

Example :

1. Thread #1 has just finished processing `user_a` file.
2. Thread #3 is still iterating through the file array and have skipped 3 files of `user_a`
3. In the current iteration for Thread #3, the file involved is the 4th file of `user_a` file.
4. As thread #1 have finished processing `user_a` file, thread #3 is given the green light to process this file (which is wrong, it should process the 1st skipped file)

For this, the logical thing is check whether there are any earlier skipped files beforehand before deciding to process.

However, I am not sure whats the best way to do this in the code level. Should I store all the skipped files in a queue, or put them in a separate folder, or is there a better way to do at code-level?

Another issue is I would like to limit the threading to maximum 200 only in order to not overwhelm the system.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes - you should simplify this. First of all, you only need the earliest file per user. You can find that by grouping per user and selecting the earliest file. To do that, you need to split the name and use the first part as an argument.  Then, you need to execute the second scripts in parallel. All of those things can be done easily, even the last, eg using  xargs or Powershell Core's Foreach with -Parallel. In xargs you need to add `-N 1 -P 8` to use 8 threads to process batches of 1 item at a time. In Powershell Core, `-Parallel -ThrottleLimit 8` will use 8 threads.

Comment: You don't need and *shouldn't* use 200 threads unless you have a 256-core machine on top of an extremely fast disk array. Otherwise the threads will simply wait to get scheduled in the available cores, and even then they'll just block waiting for IO. You should experiment to find the thread count that works best on your machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos finding the earliest file per user is achievable. but how do I code the script such that next earliest file for the user can only be processed after the existing process is done?

Comment: Why do that at all? Didn't you ask how to process only the earliest file per user? Or did you mean to say you want to process the files in order? You described what you thought the solution would look like, not your actual problem. To process each user's files in order you could feed the user names to xargs and have it run a script that lists and sorts files for that user before processing them